# Setting borderwidth to 0 still leaves a border on a sunburst graph

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts

When setting the borderWidth of my sunburst graph to 0, there are still faint white lines that show and make it look unclean. [Current appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjWEp.png)

Setting the bordercolor to something else (while the width is 0) doesn't change it. It appears that the faint white lines are actually because of the background colour being white.

My first thought was to set the border colour to the colour of the graph, but I will be using different colours across each set which makes this solution not applicable for me.

You can replicate this using the default code for a sunburst graph [here.](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=sunburst-label-rotate) Just add the below code in [this spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgE5O.png).

```
itemStyle: {
  borderWidth: 0,
  borderColor: transparent,
  },
```

Instead, does anyone have recommendations? Or should I post this as a bug on the github?